# What is the meaning of the white ship?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In film called *The Basketball Diaries (1995)*, 
Jim written this poem after having sex with hooker:

> **White ship** disappears in the wave machine this morning. Your eyes got
>   shut with secret chains that pillow armies eventually set free like
>   soft horses through toy deserts.

Do **White ship** means human sperm?

Comment: The full text of the poem is quite different from what you've quoted I think. For example, it's not "pillow armies", it's "pill armies". http://jwcampb.blogspot.com/2009/09/too-many-windows.html

Answer (score 1):

Those lines are quoted from the 1970 poem "Blood Bridge" by Jim Carroll, whose 1978 autobiography *The Basketball Diaries* was the basis for the movie.

What any line of poetry means is always up for debate, but I would guess that the white ship was a reference to the [famous shipwreck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Ship) and if it's a sexual allusion, it's to his penis, not to any effusion therefrom.